# Show LIs based on ID in sequence

Tags: jquery, events, effects

I'm working on creating a for-loop that calls a javascript effect and applies it to an LI, doing it in sequence. Here's what I've got:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        $("li#"+i).show();
    }
});
```

However, this doesn't work. I need it to apply the effect to LI#1 then LI#2, LI#3... and so on.

What I'm trying to do is similar to what Twitter does when you click the "more" button at the bottom of the page only instead of jumping I want it to ease down.

**EDIT:** I can't just wrap the LIs in a DIV as I'm going to be adding LIs to a UL element.

However, if there was a way to animate the UL as it changed size I'd be all for that.

Comment: See my edit - hopefully more helpful than before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        $("li#"+i).show("slow");
    }
});
```

Have a look at [show( speed, [callback] )](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show). From the doc:

> Show all matched elements using a
>   graceful animation and firing an
>   optional callback after completion.
>
> The height, width, and opacity of each
>   of the matched elements are changed
>   dynamically according to the specified
>   speed.

Also, there are other ways to hide and reveal elements, such as [fadeIn](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn) and [fadeOut](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut). Have a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Effects .

I did a quick mock-up of the kind of thing you are after with static data:

```
var $lis = $('<li>blha blhahah lajlkdj</li><li>blha blhahah lsdfsajlkdj</li>').hide();
$('ul').append($lis);
$lis.show("slow");
```

and it works, so it is conceivable that you could do something like the following, and not have to bother with the headache of iterating over element IDs:

```
$.load('/items/?p=2',function(data) {
    var $lis = $(data).hide();
    $('ul').append($lis);
    $lis.show("slow");
});
```

Just to be clear, the above call to [$.load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) assumes that the output of **/items/?p=2** on your site is a bunch of LIs

Answer (score 1):

if you're wanting each one to appear at the same rate, but with a slight delay in between each, you may need to use setTimeout... for example...

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    var showListItem = function(index) {
        $("li#"+index).show("slow")
    };
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        setTimeout(function() { showListItem(i); }, (i * 100))
    }
});
```

That might look a little silly, but if I remember correctly, unless you wrap your index (i) in an enclosure of some kind then the method that executes will always see the value of i as 10.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that if you're triggering this upon another event that loads new items via Ajax (like after clicking the "More" button), then you need to wrap your logic in [.live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) that is available in jQuery 1.3.

If you're using jQuery 1.2, you can use [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, if you have a list like so:

```
<ul id='menu' style='display: none;'>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
<li>item 5</li>
<li>item 6</li>
<li>item 7</li>
</ul>
```

You could then write code to show the list items sequentially like this:

```
$('#menu').show().find('li').hide().bind('show', function() {
  $(this).show('slow', function() {
    $(this).next('li').trigger('show');
  });
}).filter(':first').trigger('show');
```

The code is doing the following: Finding the menu `<ul>`, showing it, finding all the `<li>` and hiding them, binding a custom event called `show` which slowly shows the element, and once it is fully shown looks to see if there are any `<li>` next to it and triggers the same event for that element. Then we filter from all the `<li>` only the first one, and trigger this custom event for it, essentially setting off the domino effect.

[Here is an example of it at work](http://jsbin.com/idoso). If you wanted it faster you could change 'slow' to 'fast' or a time.